# String format in .NET: convert integer to fixed width string?

Tags: .net, string, string-formatting

I have an int in .NET/C# that I want to convert to a specifically formatted string.

If the value is 1, I want the string to be "001".

10 = "010".

116 = "116".

etc...

I'm looking around at string formatting, but so far no success. I also won't have values over 999.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Take a look at [`PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx).

ex:

```
int i = 40;

string s = i.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
```

s == "040"

Comment: What are the memory implications? Will it result in a higher memory load than using other methods?

Comment: Not too bad but vcsjones solution below is alot better in my opinion. At least 1 less instance of the string created for that one.

Comment: Negative numbers are at risk using this approach.  "-1" becomes "0-1"

Answer (score 66):

The simplest way to do this is use .NET's built-in functionality for this:

```
var r = 10;
var p = r.ToString("000");
```

No need for looping or padding.

Comment: did not know of this approach.. plus one :)

Comment: For negative numbers, this will become 4 chars.  For example, -10 becomes "-010"

Answer (score 13):

Another option would be:

```
i.ToString("d3")
```

Comment: @Brady Could you be more specific? It works fine for me.

Comment: Sure. As soon as the compiler hits that line, the value doesn't change, it just goes right past it as if it wasn't there. `Dim thisDate As Date`
    `Dim thisMonth As Integer`

    `thisDate = Date.Today`
    `thisMonth = Month(thisDate)`
    `thisMonth.ToString("00")` = "2" for me instead of "02".

Comment: @Brady ToString doesn't *change* anything, it *returns* the string. Maybe that's the problem? (You don't actually show how you output the value, so it's hard to tell.)

Comment: Ugh, I was trying to STORE the variable. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: For negative numbers, this will become 4 chars. For example, -10 becomes "-010"

Answer (score 7):

I recall seeing code like this to pad numbers with zeros...

```
int[] nums = new int[] { 1, 10, 116 };

foreach (int i in nums)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:000}", i);
}
```

Output:

```
001
010
116
```

Comment: That works only if you want to output them to the console. What if you want to do something else with them?

Answer (score 2):

If we want to use it in a function with variable fixed length output, then this approach

```
public string ToString(int i, int Digits)
{
 return i.ToString(string.Format("D{0}", Digits));
}
```

runs 20% faster than this

```
return i.ToString().PadLeft(Digits, '0');
```

but if we want also to use the function with a string input (e.g. HEX number) we can use this approach:

```
public string ToString(string value, int Digits)
 {
 int InsDigits= Digits - value.Length;
 return ((InsDigits> 0) ? new String('0', InsDigits) + value : value);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, this way is also possible and I prefere it because it is clearer and more flexible.

```
int value = 10;

// 010 
resultString = $"{value:000}";

// The result is: 010 
resultString = $"The result is: {value:000}";
```

Answer (score -5):

Every time I have needed to append things to the beginning of a string to match criteria like this I have used a while loop. Like so:

```
while (myString.length < 5) myString = "0" + myString;
```

Although there may be a string.format way to do this as well this has worked fine for me before.