# C# linq with server based database

Tags: c#, database, linq, desktop-application

I have problem with  **id Char(5) as a primary key**, where the project need me
to make the **id** with some *combination of number and character.*
example **P0001**, when new data's inserted, the PK of the new data is **P0002** and soon.

Can someone help me with the code?
I know about the logic, but I don't know how to get the data from database using linq.

```
context = new CarRentalLinqDataContext(); 
Car car = new Car(); 
car.carName = textBox_CarName.Text; 
int year = Int32.Parse(textBox_CarYear.Text); 
car.carYear = year; 
var id = context.Cars.Max(x => car.car_id); 
id = id.Substring(id.LastIndexOf(car.car_id)); 
int i = Convert.ToInt32(id); i += 1; 
string Code = "C000" + i.ToString(); 
car.car_id = Code; context.Cars.InsertOnSubmit(car); 
context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Show the code where you are facing LINQ issue

Comment: <code>
   context = new CarRentalLinqDataContext();

  Car car = new Car();
            
  car.carName = textBox_CarName.Text;
      int year = Int32.Parse(textBox_CarYear.Text);
  car.carYear = year;


            
  var id = context.Cars.Max(x => car.car_id);
       id = id.Substring(id.LastIndexOf(car.car_id));
   int i = Convert.ToInt32(id);
       i += 1;
  string Code = "C000" + i.ToString();
  car.car_id = Code;


 context.Cars.InsertOnSubmit(car);
 context.SubmitChanges();
</code>

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a problem in creating a new id in the given table. You may do following:

1: Since, primary keys are already known combination of chars and numbers, you can do lexical sorting of rows and get max value. See [how to select max of mixed string/int column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392753/c-sharp-finding-the-maximum-value-of-a-string-with-linq).

2: Remove all characters from a string. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729064/need-regex-to-remove-all-alphabets-from-string)

```
string intPartInKeyString = Regex.Replace(id, "[A-Za-z]", ""); // Remove all non digits
```

3: Get integer by String to int conversion: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)

```
int maxIntValueInKey = Convert.ToInt32(intPartInKeyString);
```

4: Get new Id by padding zeros to incremedted id: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399771/string-format-in-net-convert-integer-to-fixed-width-string)

```
string newId = "P" + (++maxIntValueInKey).ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
```

Comment: is it like this?
var id = context.Cars.Max(x => car.car_id);
            string intPartInKeyString = Regex.Replace(id, "[A-Za-z]", "");
            int maxIntValueInKey = Convert.ToInt32(intPartInKeyString);
            string newId = "C" + (++maxIntValueInKey).ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
            car.car_id = newId;

Comment: How to get all id in the table by using Linq?
i think it happened because i can't retrive the id 

var id = context.Cars.Max(x => car.car_id); // this isnot working

Comment: @WilliamHuang yes, your first comment seems to have correct code.



For getting maximum id, what are you getting? If its returning null, then you may do a null check like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392753/c-sharp-finding-the-maximum-value-of-a-string-with-linq